# Adding scrollbar to a window in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a software made which when resized to smaller height/width loses all the content i.e. the content hides. Is there a way to add a scrollbar to the window where the content is none of the listbox, text elc. I have already tried the canvas thing but that it really did was that it just inserted a scrollbar which did nothing.
Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: are you wanting to attach a scrollbar to a scrollable object like a listbox or text widget, or are you wanting to attach a scrollbar to the window as a whole, so that all of the contents -- buttons, labels, frames, etc) is scrollable?

Comment: I need to attach the scroll bar to the window as a whole. I tried doing it using canvas but it did not work.

Comment: Is a ScrolledFrame (http://tkinter.unpy.net/wiki/ScrolledFrame) with several bugs ok for your needs ? It works for me after commenting the lines calling `update_idletasks`. Actually, a Desktop GUI that needs scrolling as a whole is usually bad.